# Why javascript promise chaining with delaying isn't executed without resolve?

Tags: javascript, html, promise, async-await

I wanted to make the async function like after 1 second then promise1 is executed and THEN after 0.5 seconds is passed over promise1 executed then promise2 is executed. I tried this but it doesn't work. But the function works after putting `resolve()`. I got how this work but I am not still sure why it works.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');

        function painting() {
        return new Promise ((res) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
          button.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
          res();
              }, 1000);
        })
        .then(() => turnOff());
        }
            
        function turnOff() { 
        return new Promise(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
            button.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
            }, 500)
        })
        }
        
        async function startPaint() {
              return await painting()
            }
            
button.onclick = function() {startPaint()};
```

```html
<button id='button' >
hello
</button>
```

The code below is the one that doesn't work:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');

        function painting() {
        return new Promise ((res) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
          button.style.backgroundColor = 'green';          
          //res();
          //Chaining doesn't happen without res();
              }, 1000);
        })
        .then(() => turnOff());
        }
            
        function turnOff() { 
        return new Promise(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
            button.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
            }, 500)
        })
        }
        
        async function startPaint() {
              return await painting();
            }
            
button.onclick = function() {startPaint()};
```

```html
<button id='button' >
hello
</button>
```

Comment: If the promise never settles, the rest of the chain never runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new promise and you never resolve it.  You need to put a call to `res()` inside the `setTimeout()`.  A new promise you manually create is never resolved until you call the resolving function from somewhere inside the promise constructor function.  That's just how the promise constructor function works.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     // you must call resolve(someVal) or reject(someErr) inside this function
     // somewhere or the promise will never resolve or reject
     
     // for example
     setTimeout(() => {
          resolve("hello");
     }, 1000);

     // nothing happens automatically when this function finishes execution
      
}).then(val => {
     console.log(val);
}).catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
});
```

And, if your promise is never resolved or rejected, then neither the `.then()` or `.catch()` handlers are ever called.  The promise will just sit in the "pending" state forever.

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot! So when `promise isn't settled then `.then()` or `.catch()` are never called. It's clear!

Answer (score 1):

The code inside a promise needs to end with either `resolve()` or `reject()`, in order to be considered finished, so it can continue to the new step (what you've got inside `.then()`).
If neither of those calls are made (in this case, `resolve()`), then the promise hangs, and nothing else after it is executed. It's waiting.

With promises, you need to `settle` it in order to go to the next step, to say so.

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot! So to continue then new step `.then()` is needed. It's clear!

Comment: Shouldn't `.then()` be next line to `await` like `return await painting().then();`?